# Returning blank lines instead of expected, list comprehension and dictionaries

Tags: python

The code should take the changes_text.txt, and format it using dictionaries and such. Except its returning as if theres no schedule changes even though there is.

```
# Store the text data in a string variable instead of writing it to a file
raw_data = changes_txt.text
print(raw_data, 0)

# Use a dictionary to map strings to functions
operation_map = {
    'ביטול שעור': lambda line, i: f'Period {i} cancelled! W\n',
    'הזזת שיעור': lambda line, i: f'Class "{line.split(" לשיעור")[0].split(", ")[2]}" moved to period {i}\n',
    'מילוי מקום': lambda line, i: f'Period {i} replaced with class "{line.split(", ")[4]}"\n',
    'החלפת חדר': lambda line,
                        i: f'Class "{line.split(", ")[2]}" moved to room {line.split(", ")[-1].split(":")[-1]}\n',
}

# Split the raw data into lines
data_lines = raw_data.splitlines()
print(data_lines, 1)

# Use a list comprehension to apply the operations to the data
results = [operation_map[line.split(" ")[0]](line, i) if line.split(" ")[0] in operation_map else "\n"
           for line in data_lines for i in range(8)]

# Use string interpolation to format the output data
output = ''.join(results)
return output
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first word in each line match one of the operations in the dict keys?

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
results = [operation_map[line.split(" ")[0]](line, i) if line.split(" ")[0] in operation_map else "\n"
           for line in data_lines for i in range(8)]
```

you are splitting each line on " " and taking the first element but by doing this none of your dictionary items can be matched. Example your line is "ביטול שעור" the line.split(" ")[0] will return "ביטול". It can't match because your keys all include " " but by doing split(" ")[0] you remove all " " resulting in no matches.